# shortcut to resize explorer panel in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-keybinding

Is there any shortcut to resize explorer panel in VS Code?

By the way, I know how to search for keyboards in vs code and I have already implemented some resizing functionalities for terminal, editor panel and other stuff. I specifically wanna know if there is any shortcut for resizing the Explorer View and not anything else.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, there isn't a keyboard shortcut to resize a specific view regardless of what view is currently focused (at least- not at the time of this writing), but there exist keyboard shortcut commands to resize the currently focused view: `workbench.action.increaseViewSize` and `workbench.action.decreaseViewSize`. What you can do is bind something to those commands, and then focus the Explorer View (bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>), and then use your keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thank you.  I searched for "resize" in visual studio code keyboard shortcuts and I couldn't find this one. We can also use *workbench.action.terminal.resizePaneDown* or *workbench.action.terminal.resizePaneUp* to resize the terminal towards down or up respectively. but keep in mind it's only for the terminal and not for the explorer panel.